# Comparison of strings for Mastermind game

Tags: c, string, compare, pattern-matching

I am writing a program that simulates the game Mastermind, but I am struggling with how to compare guessed pattern to key pattern.
The game conditions are a little bit changed:

- patterns consist of letters.
- if an element of guessed pattern is equal to element of key pattern, and also index is equal, then print b.
- if an element of guessed pattern is equal to element of key pattern, but index is not, then print w.
- if an element of guessed pattern is not equal to element of key pattern, print dot.
- in feedback about guessed pattern, 'b's come first, 'w's second, '.'s last.

#### Original key vs guess pattern match code

```
    for (i=0; i<patternlength; i++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<patternlength; x++)
        {
           if (guess[i]==key[x] && i==x)
                printf("b");
            if (guess[i]==key[x] && i!=x)
                printf("w");
            if (guess[i]!=key[x])
                printf(".");
        }   
    }
```

#### Revised code

This is using some of the answer provided by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler).  Unfotunately, it isn't working correctly yet; can you help me?

The functions length() and guessnum() are defined already.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int length()
{
  int length;
  printf("Enter the pattern length: ");
  scanf("%d", &length);
  return length;
}
int guessnum()
{
  int guessnum;
  printf("Enter the number of guesses: ");
  scanf("%d", &guessnum);
  return guessnum;
}
int main(void)
{
  int patternlength = length();
  char key[patternlength+1];      
  char keyc[patternlength+1];    
  int numguess = guessnum();
  char guess[patternlength+1];    
  printf("Input the key pattern with no spaces: ");
  scanf("%s", key);
  int i,j,count = 1;
  int bcount = 0, wcount = 0;
  char guessc[patternlength+1];
  guessc[0] = '\0';            
  int ind;
  char output[patternlength];
  for (ind=0; ind<(patternlength+1); ind++)
    output[ind]='\0';
  char outputc[patternlength+1];
  char guessold[patternlength+1];
  for (ind=0; ind<(patternlength+1); ind++)
  guessold[ind]='\0';
  while (strcmp(key, guess) !=0 && count<=numguess)
    {
      if(count>1)
    strcpy(guessold, guess);
      strcpy(keyc, key);          
      printf("Input a guess pattern with no spaces: ");
      scanf("%s", guess);
      if (count>1)
    printf("%d: %s %s\n", count-1, output, guessold);
      strcpy(guessc, guess);
      wcount = 0;    
      bcount = 0;     
      printf("%d: ", count);
      for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
    {
      if (keyc[i] == guessc[i])
        {
          putchar('b');
          keyc[i] = guessc[i] = '.';
          bcount++;
          for (ind=0; ind<patternlength; ind++)
        output[ind]='b';
        }
    }
      if (bcount != patternlength)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
        {
          if (guessc[i] != '.')
        {

          for (j = 0; j < patternlength; j++)
            {

              if (guessc[i] == keyc[j])
            {
              wcount++;
              putchar('w');
              for (ind=0; ind<patternlength; ind++)
                if (output[ind]!='b')
                  output[ind]='w';

              keyc[j] = guessc[i] = '.';
              break;
            }
            }
        }
        }
      for (i = bcount  +  wcount; i < patternlength; i++)
        putchar('.');
      for (ind=bcount+wcount; ind<patternlength; ind++)
        output[ind]='.';
    }
      count++;
      printf(" %s\n", guess);
      strcpy(outputc, output);
    }
  if (strcmp(key, guess) != 0)
    {
      printf("You did not guess the pattern!\n");
    }
  else 
    {
      printf("You guessed the pattern!\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

output of code above:

```
Enter the pattern length: 3
Enter the number of guesses: 3
Input the key pattern with no spaces: abc
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: acb
1: bww acb
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abb
1: bbb acb
2: bb. abb
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abc
2: bb. abb
3: bbb abc
You guessed the pattern!
```

***required output:***

```
    Enter the pattern length: 3
    Enter the number of guesses: 3
    Input the key pattern with no spaces: abc
    Input a guess pattern with no spaces: acb
    1: bww acb
    Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abb
    1: bww acb
    2: bb. abb
    Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abc
    1: bww acb
    2: bb. abb
    3: bbb abc
    You guessed the pattern!
```

I tried to use one more string, which will store in it feedback of the guess, but when there are several guesses, i think i should use some kind of loop to print feedback of all previous guesses each time new guess is made. but it is difficult to me figure out how should i write this loop with the structure suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler).

I added my last correction to the code, so I almost reached the desired output. does anyone have an idea what is possible to do here?

Comment: @GajananH, i posted my code, i always end up with a partially correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that there is a structure (for easy copying of the array contained within it), and that the input validation ensures that the key and the guess are the same length, and that the key and the guess only contain alphabetic characters.

```
typedef struct pattern
{
    char pattern[8];
} pattern;

size_t print_scoring(pattern key, pattern guess)
{
    size_t n = strlen(key.pattern);
    assert(n == strlen(guess.pattern));
    size_t bcount = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (key.pattern[i] == guess.pattern[i])
        {
            putchar('b');
            key.pattern[i] = guess.pattern[i] = '.';
            bcount++;
        }
    }
    if (bcount != n)
    {
        size_t wcount = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (guess.pattern[i] != '.')
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (guess.pattern[i] == key.pattern[j])
                    {
                        wcount++;
                        putchar('w');
                        guess.pattern[i] = key.pattern[j] = '.';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (size_t i = bcount + wcount; i < n; i++)
            putchar('.');
    }
    return bcount;
}
```

The function works on copies of the key and the pattern (the structures are passed by value, not by pointer).  It returns the number of correct guesses in the correct position; it assumes the calling code knows how long the pattern is, so the calling code can tell when the pattern is correct.  It marks guess and key characters as 'used' by replacing them with a '.'.  This is important to prevent a key of `"aba"` and a guess of `"aaa"` being incorrectly marked as `bbw` rather than correctly as `bb.`.  This would be more important in keys/guesses of length 4 or more.

#### Test Harness

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { NUM_KEYS = 3, NUM_GUESSES = 5 };
    pattern k[] = { { "abc" }, { "aba" }, { "aaa" } };
    pattern g[] = { { "aaa" }, { "aab" }, { "abc" }, { "cba" }, { "bab" } };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_GUESSES; j++)
        {
            printf("Key: %s; Guess %s; Score: ", k[i].pattern, g[j].pattern);
            size_t n = print_scoring(k[i], g[j]);
            if (n == 3)
                printf(" -- Correct!");
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

#### Test Output

```
Key: abc; Guess aaa; Score: b..
Key: abc; Guess aab; Score: bw.
Key: abc; Guess abc; Score: bbb -- Correct!
Key: abc; Guess cba; Score: bww
Key: abc; Guess bab; Score: ww.
Key: aba; Guess aaa; Score: bb.
Key: aba; Guess aab; Score: bww
Key: aba; Guess abc; Score: bb.
Key: aba; Guess cba; Score: bb.
Key: aba; Guess bab; Score: ww.
Key: aaa; Guess aaa; Score: bbb -- Correct!
Key: aaa; Guess aab; Score: bb.
Key: aaa; Guess abc; Score: b..
Key: aaa; Guess cba; Score: b..
Key: aaa; Guess bab; Score: b..
```

---

### From the comments

> Why is my code not working? Can you have a look at it please? 
>   The problem is that I cannot go the next step after entering a guess pattern. Maybe I don't see some mistakes in my code.

Instant response:

One of the key points in my answer is that the comparison code is working on copies of the data entered. It is a destructive comparison algorithm, writing dots over the data. Your attempt to merge my code into your program did not retain the separate function working on separate copies of the data which were a crucial part of this answer. The use of a structure was there to make it easy to pass copies of the data around (it's the one time C copies arrays for you automatically). The comparison code should be in a function of its own, not inline in `main()`.

However, we can get the code given to work.  There were some transcription errors (marked BUG below), and some other problems (also identified below).

#### Working version of revised code in question

This is a working version of your program annotated with the crucial changes.  Non-crucial changes include spacing around operators and using an indent level of 4 spaces.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int length(void) { return 3; }    // Dummy function
static int guessnum(void) { return 5; }  // Dummy function

int main(void)
{
    int patternlength = length();
    char key[patternlength+1];      // Buffer overflow
    char keyc[patternlength+1];     // Copy of key
    int numguess = guessnum();
    char guess[patternlength+1];    // Buffer overflow
    printf("Input the key pattern with no spaces: ");
    scanf("%s", key);
    int i,j,count = 1;
    int bcount = 0, wcount = 0;
    char guessc[patternlength+1];   // Buffer overflow
    guessc[0] = '\0';               // Initialize!
    while (strcmp(key, guess) != 0 && count <= numguess)
    {
        strcpy(keyc, key);          // Copy key too
        printf("Input a guess pattern with no spaces: ");
        scanf("%s", guess);
        strcpy(guessc, guess);

        wcount = 0;     // Reinitialize
        bcount = 0;     // Reinitialize
        printf("%d: ", count);
        for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
        {
            if (keyc[i] == guessc[i])
            {
                putchar('b');
                keyc[i] = guessc[i] = '.';
                bcount++;
            }
        }
        if (bcount != patternlength)    // Extraneous semi-colon excised! ;
        {
            for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
            {
                if (guessc[i] != '.')
                {
                    //for (j = 0; i < patternlength; j++) BUG
                    for (j = 0; j < patternlength; j++)
                    {
                        //if (guessc[i] == keyc[i]) BUG
                        if (guessc[i] == keyc[j])
                        {
                            wcount++;
                            putchar('w');
                            //guessc[i] = keyc[i];  BUG
                            keyc[j] = guessc[i] = '.';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = bcount  +  wcount; i < patternlength; i++)
                putchar('.');
        }
        count++;
        printf(" %s\n", guess);
    }
    if (strcmp(key, guess) != 0)
    {
        printf("You did not guess the pattern!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("You guessed the pattern!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler told me about the stray semi-colon:

```
ss2.c: In function ‘main’:
ss2.c:36:37: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
```

If your compiler didn't tell you about that, you aren't using enough warnings (or you need a better compiler).  I routinely use:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition ss2.c -o ss2
```

The working code passes that without a whimper.

#### Sample output

```
Input the key pattern with no spaces: abc
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: aaa
1: b.. aaa
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: bbb
2: b.. bbb
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: ccc
3: b.. ccc
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: cab
4: www cab
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abc
5: bbb abc
You guessed the pattern!
```

#### Final debug-laden code

This is mainly to show the level of printing that I used to see what was going wrong.  Using `stderr` for the diagnostic output meant the diagnostics did not interfere with the buffering of `stdout` as the output line was built up.  That and the use of no indentation on the debug code also meant it was easy to strip the debug code out.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int length(void) { return 3; }
static int guessnum(void) { return 5; }

int main(void)
{
    int patternlength = length();
    char key[patternlength+1];      // Buffer overflow
    char keyc[patternlength+1];     // Copy of key
    int numguess = guessnum();
    char guess[patternlength+1];    // Buffer overflow
    printf("Input the key pattern with no spaces: ");
    scanf("%s", key);
    int i,j,count = 1;
    int bcount = 0, wcount = 0;
    char guessc[patternlength+1];   // Buffer overflow
    guessc[0] = '\0';               // Initialize!
    while (strcmp(key, guess) != 0 && count <= numguess)
    {
        strcpy(keyc, key);          // Copy key too
        printf("Input a guess pattern with no spaces: ");
        scanf("%s", guess);
        strcpy(guessc, guess);

fprintf(stderr, "B1: (%s) vs (%s)\n", key, guess);
fprintf(stderr, "B2: (%s) vs (%s)\n", keyc, guessc);
        wcount = 0;     // Reinitialize
        bcount = 0;     // Reinitialize
        printf("%d: ", count);
        for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
        {
fprintf(stderr, "L1a: %d\n", i);
            if (keyc[i] == guessc[i])
            {
fprintf(stderr, "L1b: B (%c = %c)\n", keyc[i], guessc[i]);
                putchar('b');
                keyc[i] = guessc[i] = '.';
                bcount++;
            }
        }
fprintf(stderr, "M1: (%s) vs (%s)\n", keyc, guessc);
        if (bcount != patternlength)    // Extraneous semi-colon excised! ;
        {
fprintf(stderr, "L2a: b = %d (%s) vs (%s)\n", bcount, keyc, guessc);
            for (i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
            {
fprintf(stderr, "L2b: %d (%c)\n", i, guessc[i]);
                if (guessc[i] != '.')
                {
fprintf(stderr, "L2c: %d (%c)\n", i, guessc[i]);
                    //for (j = 0; i < patternlength; j++) BUG
                    for (j = 0; j < patternlength; j++)
                    {
fprintf(stderr, "L2d: %d (%c) vs %d (%c)\n", i, guessc[i], j, keyc[j]);
                        //if (guessc[i] == keyc[i]) BUG
                        if (guessc[i] == keyc[j])
                        {
fprintf(stderr, "L2e: W %d (%c) vs %d (%c)\n", i, guessc[i], j, keyc[j]);
                            wcount++;
                            putchar('w');
                            keyc[j] = guessc[i] = '.';
                            //guessc[i] = keyc[i];  BUG
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
fprintf(stderr, "L3a: %d + %d vs %d\n", bcount, wcount, patternlength);
            for (i = bcount  +  wcount; i < patternlength; i++)
fprintf(stderr, "L3b: D %d\n", i),
                putchar('.');
        }
        count++;
        printf(" %s\n", guess);
    }
    if (strcmp(key, guess) != 0)
    {
        printf("You did not guess the pattern!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("You guessed the pattern!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the trick with the comma operator after the last `fprintf()` function call.

#### Keeping a record of previous guesses and marks

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void err_exit(const char *msg, ...);
static void prompt_str(const char *prompt, int bufsiz, char *buffer);
static int  prompt_int(const char *prompt);

int main(void)
{
    int  patternlength = prompt_int("Length of key");
    int  numguess = prompt_int("Number of guesses");
    char key[patternlength+1];
    char guesses[numguess][patternlength+1];
    char marks[numguess][patternlength+1];
    int  count = 0;

    prompt_str("Input the key pattern with no spaces", patternlength, key);

    while (count < numguess)
    {
        char guess[patternlength+1];
        char keyc[patternlength+1];
        char mark[patternlength+1];
        char *marker = mark;
        int wcount = 0;
        int bcount = 0;

        strcpy(keyc, key);
        prompt_str("Input a guess pattern with no spaces", patternlength, guess);
        strcpy(guesses[count], guess);

        for (int i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
        {
            if (keyc[i] == guess[i])
            {
                *marker++ = 'b';
                keyc[i] = guess[i] = '.';
                bcount++;
            }
        }
        if (bcount == patternlength)
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < patternlength; i++)
        {
            if (guess[i] == '.')
                continue;
            for (int j = 0; j < patternlength; j++)
            {
                if (guess[i] == keyc[j])
                {
                    wcount++;
                    *marker++ = 'w';
                    keyc[j] = guess[i] = '.';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = bcount  +  wcount; i < patternlength; i++)
            *marker++ = '.';
        *marker = '\0';
        strcpy(marks[count], mark);
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            printf("Guess: %d [%s] marks [%s]\n", i, guesses[i], marks[i]);
    }
    if (count >= numguess)
        printf("You did not guess the pattern (which was [%s])!\n", key);
    else 
        printf("You guessed the pattern!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void prompt_str(const char *prompt, int bufsiz, char *buffer)
{
    char fmt[8];
    int  c;

    sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", bufsiz);
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    if (scanf(fmt, buffer) != 1)
        err_exit("Unexpected input failure\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}

static int prompt_int(const char *prompt)
{
    int number;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
        err_exit("Unexpected input failure\n");
    if (number <= 0 || number > 9)
        err_exit("Number should be in the range 1..9 (not %d)\n", number);
    return(number);
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}
```

Introduced functions `prompt_int()` and `prompt_str()` to get data.  The `prompt_str()` function is reasonably resilient against overflows.  There's an error reporting function.  The dummy functions are replaced. Here is some sample output.  From here on, you're on your own!

```
Length of key: 4
Number of guesses: 8
Input the key pattern with no spaces: abcd
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: aaaa
Guess: 0 [aaaa] marks [b...]
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: dcba
Guess: 0 [aaaa] marks [b...]
Guess: 1 [dcba] marks [wwww]
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: cdba
Guess: 0 [aaaa] marks [b...]
Guess: 1 [dcba] marks [wwww]
Guess: 2 [cdba] marks [wwww]
Input a guess pattern with no spaces: abcd
You guessed the pattern!
```

Comment: sir, i think i don't get something...why my code is not working? can you have a look at it please?
i am posting it in header

Comment: the problem is that i cannot go the next step after entering a guess pattern. maybe i don't see some mistakes in my code.

Comment: One of the key points in my answer is that the comparison code is working on copies of the data entered.  It is a destructive comparison algorithm, writing dots over the data.  Your attempt to merge my code into your program did not retain the separate function working on separate copies of the data which were a crucial part of this answer.  The use of a structure was there to make it easy to pass copies of the data around (it's the one time C copies arrays for you automatically).  The comparison code should be in a function of its own, not inline in `main()`. I'll look at your code some more.

Comment: oh, i was surprised how detailed you explained everything. thank you very much. but i still have one more question, your code supposes that in output i does not print previous guess patterns, as new guess is made. i am thinking of declaring another string, which will store in it characters 'b', 'w', '.', and the print it, but if there are several guesses, it will be a little bit difficult to so. may be there is another way of doing it? (i am talking about output which i showed in first post.)

Comment: and about compiler. it did not five any warning when compiling. i have to use this compiler:  
`gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: If you want the '`bw.`' pattern in a string (instead of being output to `stdout`), then have a variable `char marks[patternlength+1];`, to which you add the characters instead of using `putchar()`. Remember to add a null at the end. If you have a function, it is a parameter to the function; if you still have the code in `main()`, you manage it there. You can then print that string as you see fit. Regarding compiler: since you're using `gcc`, make sure you always compile with at least `-Wall`. I've been coding in C for over 25 years, and I don't trust my code until it compiles without warnings.

Comment: but how I will keep record of all feedback patterns in one string?

Comment: oh, i think you got me wrong, i just said which characters i need to store in this new string. they don't have to be 'bw.' exactly

Comment: before you commented, i tried to do something similar to what you suggested, but i always get this symbol 'ʦ' at the end of new string, even if added null at the end. **i corrected this problem**

Comment: sir, I still couldn't solve the problem with the output of the previous guess and their feedback. do yo have any idea on this part?

Comment: I would only expect to keep one of the `bw.` patterns (which I understood to be the pattern of `b`'s, `w`'s and `.`'s, not specifically the sequence `bw.`) in a single string.  If you can say what you want a bit more clearly, we can do it.  It might be that you need an array of strings, one per guess that's allowed.  What should the output look like?

Comment: the exact output is written in the my question.

Comment: each time a new guess is made(until you use all of your allowed chances, or guess the correct pattern), all of the previously done guesses should be shown in the output. in the order as they came up.

Comment: Look at the new code (Keeping a record of previous guesses and marks).

Comment: yeah. it worked as needed. thanks. but i think you used techniques which i don't know yet. thank you very much, i will try later to improve my version of correct output, which i posted in my question, and also try to understand your code. thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are basically matching all the elements of `key` with all elements of `guess`, which is not what you want.

You need to iterate on `guess` and differentiate the three cases

1. Element guessed correctly
2. Element not guessed correctly but present in the key
3. Element not guessed correctly and not present in the key

   ```
   int i,k;
   bool found;

   for (i=0; i<patternlength; i++)
   {
       if (key[i] == guess[i])
       {
           printf("b");
       }
       else
       {
           found = false;
           for (k=0; k<patternlength && !found; k++)
           {
               if (key[k] == guess[i])
               {
                   found = true;
                   printf("w");
               }
           }
           if (!found)
           {
               printf(".");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note that in the internal loop, I stop when I find an element with `&& !found`. Otherwise, I'd fall into a problem similar to yours (It will print `w` for every element that matches my guess present in `key`)

Comment: I think that given pattern 'abc' and guess 'cba', you will output a 'w' for the guessed 'c' in the wrong place before outputting the 'b' for 'b' in the correct place.  So, your scoring would be 'wbw' rather than the correct 'bww' for the given pattern.  I think you have to do it in two passes (a 'b' pass, a 'w' pass, and dot fill to the output length), but haven't verified that.  Similarly, given pattern 'aba' and guess 'aaa', you need to output 'bb.' but I think you'd output 'bwb'.